# how to update the flash plugin of WebView control

Tags: java, flash, javafx-2

Is their any way, to update the flash plugin of WebView control, in JavaFx2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a flash plugin for JavaFX WebView control.